# How to work with fragments more than just display them?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity

I know, you've probably heard this question a lot but I can't find a solution to it.

I have an activity with a layout file and it's working fine. Then I tried to merge this in a fragment. I thought I could just put the code in the main activity and it should work but nothing is happening. I tried to put it in the fragment activity but there it's not working, too.

```
val seekbar=findViewById<View>(R.id.seekbar)as? SeekBar
seekbar?.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object: SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{

override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, progress: Int, p2: Boolean) {
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,progress.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {

            }
            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {

            }
        })
```

Sorry when I'm annoying you but I'm starting with android and trying to make small steps and learn more and more. Probably in this case I don't have an idea what I have to google for.

Answer (score 1):

[Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) don't have the same lifecycles than [Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities), in fragments you have to declare the UI layout elements in **`onCreateView()`** and all the java work in **`onViewCreated()`**